# VBScript - relative path not working

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm trying to use a relative path to reference a cab file named wsusscn2.cab from a VBscript. For some reason, it's not working. The wsusscn2.cab is located in the same directory as the script. Based on the documentation I've read, this SHOULD work, but doesn't:

```
Set UpdateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set UpdateServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "..\wsusscn2.cab")
Set UpdateSearcher = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCRLF

UpdateSearcher.ServerSelection = 3 ' ssOthers

UpdateSearcher.ServiceID = UpdateService.ServiceID

Set SearchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

Set Updates = SearchResult.Updates

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine when using wssuscan.cab:" & vbCRLF

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
Next

WScript.Quit
```

Generates this error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.(backslash)` from the wsusscn2.cab? The `.(backslash)` will assume the working directory, so it may be looking one directory up, and thus not finding the .cab file. So it'd just be: `Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "wsusscn2.cab")`

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the backslash.

Comment: Have you tried placing the entire path to the file in the same area? e.g.: `Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "C:\test\wsussc2.cab")`

Comment: Can you give my answer a shot and let me know how it goes?

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, neither worked. The complete path does work, however, that wasn't my question.

Comment: Bill, I just tried my code locally and it worked great. However, I did miss an `n` in the filename when I initially answered the question. So maybe that's why it failed. Anyways. If you want, give it a shot, if not, good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "../wsusscn2.cab")
```

but be sure that this cab is in the folder one level above the page you calling for it, that is what you have there.

or if cab in the same folder do it like this:

```
  Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "wsusscn2.cab")
```

Comment: Tried both suggestions but it's still generating the same error. Perhaps the UpdateServiceManager object doesn't respect relative paths?

Comment: By the way, this DOES work with a full path. ex: "C:\wsuccn2.cab"

Comment: Would you mind expand your code to show how did you defined both UpdateService and UpdateServiceManager

Comment: You can try to put Server.MapPath("../wsusscn2.cab") because just moving file around does not solve anything. You need to make sure that file in location where your script can find it and have proper permission to use it.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the entire script. This is a sample script from MSDN. I'm simply trying to make it portable, so I can run it from a thumbdrive.

Comment: Tried wrapping it with the Server.MapPath got this error:Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Server'

Comment: That's because `Server.` is used in ASP vbscript, entirely different.

Comment: @BillWestrup If you did it in a first place I could of told you straight from the beginning. Edited your question to include proper tags.

Comment: @Blond Sorry, I'm new to vbscript. I'm simply trying to modify this to run from a thumb drive. I'm not really a programmer...although I do create oneliners to get stuff done. I need to collect info from multiple machines.

Comment: @BillWestrup No problem, just keep in mind that setting tags on your question will most likely speed up answer and also help to avoid answers which is irrelevant to your specific situations. I gave you proper answer for ASP Vbscript and it would work on IIS but you needed it for Windows which is completely different approach. And even without tags if you posted important parts of the code to begin with anyone would of see that you asking about Windows VBScript - would again speed up answer for you.

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft has made scripting so complicated that it's not even possible to ask an intelligent question. Sorry! I didn't realize VB had different flavors... Still no luck however. I'm simply going to copy the file to a known location on the c: drive and then delete it after the script runs. Crude but thats what I'm reduced to. It's a shame Windows scripting isn't more sane...

Comment: Could it be that your approach is not on the right path? What is your goal there?

Comment: I just want to run the script from a thumb drive but I can't hard code a path to thumb drive, so I need to use relative paths. I need to gather lists of missing updates from workstations.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the .AddScanPackageService() method does not allow relative paths within it's methods. To repair this, while still maintaining flexible code. You can make the path of the script location via `Wscript.ScriptFullName` and append it infront of `wsussc2.cab`. This will maintain the path of the script. So it should work as long as the script and .cab file are together.

```
 Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\")) & "wsusscn2.cab")
```

Answer (score 0):

When I hit this, I wondered if it might've been service permissions vs file location, but nope, just absolute file paths needed.

I used the FileSystemObject's GetAbsolutePathName function to determine the full path, which allows you to throw random relative paths in (like "..\reports\something\blah.cab" or just "local.cab" if you so desire.)

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CabFileArg = Wscript.Arguments(0)  ' (cscript updatecheck.vbs wsusscn2.cab)
CabFileAbs = fso.GetAbsolutePathname(CabFileArg)
```

Then the usual stuff, just using CabFileAbs instead.

```
Set UpdateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set UpdateServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline CAB", CabFileAbs , 1)
Set UpdateSearcher = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
```

… etc