# VBS AddScanPackageService Error 800A0005 Invalid Procedure or argument

Tags: vbscript

I need to use Windows Update Agent to check for security updates in remote computers. I placed a .cab file in a network drive, and I will start a VB script in several computer. The attached code is not completed yet, I am just testing. My idea is to have the script storing the results in a database. The script runs well when the .cab is placed in a local drive, but it is failing trying to access the .cab in a network drive (all users have access to that drive). The error is triggered by the AddScanPackageService: Invalid Procedure or argument. Could somebody give a clue?

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then    
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
      , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
   
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim path 
path = "\\dozer\public\wsusscn2.cab"

Set UpdateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set UpdateServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", path, 1)
Set UpdateSearcher = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCrLf


UpdateSearcher.ServerSelection = 3 

UpdateSearcher.ServiceID = UpdateService.ServiceID

Set SearchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

Set Updates = SearchResult.Updates

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine when using wssuscan.cab:" & vbCRLF
Dim update
update = ""
For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
   
    
Next
 
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298555/vbscript-relative-path-not-working) help?

Comment: Doubt you can just pass a UNC path and expect it to work, have you tried a mapped drive and specifying the full path or even just using a relative path?

Comment: Thanks Rno, I will check it :)

Comment: Hey user692942, I used an absolute path to the local computer.  I moved the file to C:and it worked well. The problem is placing the file in a network drive. I could try to copy the .cab from a network drive to the target remote computer and  then use a path to a local file. However, due to the pandemia, I have most of the users working from home, and that action takes time over a VPN connection

Comment: Well, I could not use an UNC with AddScanPackage Service. I modify  the script to ad previous step. That step copies the .cab to the local drive in the target computer. Thanks anyway Rno and user692942